# WordPress Site Health contains critical errors unless CiviCRM is disabled

Tags: wordpress, error

I uninstalled all WordPress Plugins (except CiviCRM). Then, I uninstalled all CiviCRM Extensions and Components.

Only when I disable the CiviCRM plugin does this error disappear:

[image: Site Health errors caused by CiviCRM]

WordPress 5.4

CiviCRM 5.22.1 / 5.23.4

---

```
The REST API encountered an error
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)


Your site could not complete a loopback request
Loopback requests are used to run scheduled events, and are also used by the built-in editors for themes and plugins to verify code stability.

The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on [Mr. Burns](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/2629/andy-burns)' comforting response above, and [Mr. Earnhardt's instruction](https://wearnhardt.com/2019/05/how-to-disable-tests-in-the-wordpress-site-health-check-tool/) on how to selectively remove tests, I added the following code to the functions.php file in my WordPress theme:

```
function prefix_remove_rest_availability( $tests ) {
    unset( $tests['direct']['rest_availability'] );
    return $tests;
}
add_filter( 'site_status_tests', 'prefix_remove_rest_availability' );

function prefix_remove_loopback_requests( $tests ) {
    unset( $tests['async']['loopback_requests'] );
    return $tests;
}
add_filter( 'site_status_tests', 'prefix_remove_loopback_requests' );
```

Thank you, Gentlemen! Fixed!

Comment: Dia, thanks, I used your solution as basis for a plugin https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/civicoop/wordpress/suppresses-civicrm-checks . The difference is that it also surpresses the 'php_sessions' test.

Answer (score 5):

Do not worry, the Health Check loopbacks and REST API checks are inaccurate. Nothing is actually wrong. You can install [Disable Health Check](https://develop.tadpole.cc/plugins/disable-health-check).

Comment: Could I ask what your basis is for saying they are inaccurate? So far, I've found nothing online that indicates this, or why CiviCRM causes the cURL error 28 in Site Health. I'd really prefer not to disable Site Health checks. Thanks!

Comment: @RiverRunner see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/32

Comment: @WilliamMortada Ah, I see. Thanks for the link! That sheds some good light on the issue.