# CiviCRM 5.28.2 triggering "critical issue" in WordPress 5.5 Site Health

Tags: wordpress, error

This is related to [WordPress Site Health contains critical errors unless CiviCRM is disabled](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/wordpress-site-health-contains-critical-errors-unless-civicrm-is-disabled) but I'm raising it because

1. WordPress 5.5 adds the "active PHP session was detected" issue
2. There was no response to RiverRunner's request for the basis for saying the test are inaccurate

I'm currently running WordPress 5.5 and CiviCRM 5.28.2.

The Site Health function in WordPress 5.5 reports 3 three "critical issues" related to the WP REST API.

1. An active PHP session was detected - A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.
2. The REST API encountered an error - The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.
   The REST API request failed due to an error.
   Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10005 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)
3. Your site could not complete a loopback request - Loopback requests are used to run scheduled events, and are also used by the built-in editors for themes and plugins to verify code stability.
   The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
   Error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)

[This discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/critical-issue-active-php-session/) suggests that the problem is with plugins and themes that need to be updated. By elimination, I found that CiviCRM 5.28.2 was triggering the error.

Can these "critical issues" safely be ignored and, if so, why or under what conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SiteHealth does not account for sessions and CiviCRM depnds on them. See the discussion at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/32

Possible fix:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/35234/155

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep Nayak. The discussion gives me a much better understanding.