# CiviMobileAPI / CiviCRM WP REST API error, and possibly related: WordPress - Site Health reporting REST API errors

Tags: wordpress, rest, civimobile

### Issue started when getting an error when trying to authenticate with CiviMobile - via phone. I msged the CiviMobile folk and they replied, copying me with this note:

### When we use any CIviCRM API (For example: [https://chasethemusic.org/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=(*KEY1*)&key=(*KEY2)&json={"sequential":1}](https://chasethemusic.org/wp-json/civicrm/v3/rest?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=(*KEY1*)&key=(*KEY2)&json=%7B%22sequential%22:1%7D)) we have the next error:
{
"code": "rest_not_logged_in",
"message": "You are not currently logged in.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
} .
But we still think the problem related with WordPress code (plugins, maybe Core code). You can also address issue about this error to developers of "CiviCRM WP REST API" plugin(https://github.com/mecachisenros/civicrm-wp-rest).

At this point, I noticed a Word Press Site Health error -
The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: [] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

and also a loopback error -
The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected.
Error encountered: (0) cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received_

I disabled all WordPress plugins. Then, added them back. Turns out re-activating CiviCRM brings back these errors (which may be the cause of the problem with CiviMobile?).

[WordPress Site Health contains critical errors unless CiviCRM is disabled](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/wordpress-site-health-contains-critical-errors-unless-civicrm-is-disabled)
makes it seem like the problem/error isn't real. So, maybe it's not related to the CiviMobile API / CiviCRM WP REST API situation? But???

I don't know if you have any other hints on where I should look.

CiviCRM 5.28.2
WP 5.5.1
PHP 7.4.9
CiviMobileAPI 5.3.0
CiviCRM WP REST API 0.1

THANKS!
..clark

Comment: I cannot speak to CiviMobile, but I can guarantee that Site Health NEVER contemplated a plugin with php sessions and it's results are not valid in relation to CiviCRM.  I disable and remove all notices on my sites.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the assumption that you do not require CiviCRM WP REST API plugin anymore if you are on 5.28.x

To ignore the Site Health error you install a [small plugin](https://github.com/pradpnayak/civi_health_check) that i have created.