# An active PHP session was detected

Tags: php

I'm running CiviCRM v5.32.2 and the CiviCRM WP REST API v0.1 plugin in Wordpress v5.6.

In Wordpress Site Health Status i get this warning:

```
An active PHP session was detected

A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.
```

Do you know if this error is related to CiviCRM, and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The same questions was asked at [WordPress Site Health contains critical errors unless CiviCRM is disabled](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/wordpress-site-health-contains-critical-errors-unless-civicrm-is-disabled) and had some good answers.

Summary:

- Yes CiviCRM is to blame for the notice.
- No - it's not a real problem.
- Plugins exists to suppress the notice.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!